# OkHttp Call timeout from Retrofit Interceptor using Annotations is not applied

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to use a recently added feature from OkHttp 3.12.0: full-operation timeouts.
For that, I also rely on the new `Invocation` class from retrofit 2.5.0 that allows me to retrieve the method annotations.

The annotation is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Timeout {

    int value();

    TimeUnit unit();

}
```

The retrofit interface is:

```
public interface AgentApi {

    @Timeout(value = 100, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @GET("something")
    Call<String> getSomething();

}
```

And the interceptor is:

```
class TimeoutInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        final Invocation tag = request.tag(Invocation.class);
        final Method method = tag != null ? tag.method() : null;
        final Timeout timeout = method != null ? method.getAnnotation(Timeout.class) : null;
        if (timeout != null) {
            chain.call().timeout().timeout(timeout.value(), timeout.unit());
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

}
```

I've correctly added the TimeoutInterceptor with `.addInterceptor(...)` in the OkHttpClient provided to the Retrofit Builder.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I expected. The calls are not failing when the timeout is reached?

Though it works fine when using the chain methods from the interceptor:

```
chain
  .withConnectTimeout(connect, unit)
  .withReadTimeout(read, unit)
  .withWriteTimeout(write, unit)
```

Is this because the call timeout must be set before the call is enqueued? (and the Interceptor is triggered too late in the process?), or is this something else?

Comment: That's really strange. I made a similiar test here and happens the same thing. It works If I use the old methods to set timeout at the interceptor, but when I try to change using `full-operation timeoust` it is ignored. It only works when I set at the `OkHttpClientBuilder`. At documentation it says we can should use by the `OkHttpClientBuilder.callTimeout()` or by `Call.timeout()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you are right. It is because `OkHttpClient` gets timeouts before it executes interceptors chain. If you look at `Response execute()` method in [okhttp3.RealCall](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/adb609f7f305f7ae01d877255ee70789f71feb1e/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RealCall.java) class you will find line `timeout.enter()` that is where `OkHttp` schedules timeouts and it is invoked before `getResponseWithInterceptorChain()` which is place where interceptors are executed.

Fortunately you can write workaround for that :) 
Put your `TimeoutInterceptor` in `okhttp3` package (you can create that package in your app). That will allow you to have access to `RealCall` object which has package visibility. Your `TimeoutInterceptor` class should look like this:

```
package okhttp3;

public class TimeoutInterceptor implements Interceptor {

   @Override
   public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
       Request request = chain.request();
       Invocation tag = request.tag(Invocation.class);
       Method method = tag != null ? tag.method() : null;
       Timeout timeout = method != null ? method.getAnnotation(Timeout.class) : null;
       if (timeout != null) {
           chain.call().timeout().timeout(timeout.value(), timeout.unit());
           RealCall realCall = (RealCall) chain.call();
           realCall.timeout.enter();
       }
       return chain.proceed(request);
   }
}
```

Workaround consists in executing `timeout.enter()` once again after changing timeout. 
All magic happen in lines:

```
RealCall realCall = (RealCall) chain.call();
realCall.timeout.enter();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I'd also add `realCall.timeout.exit()` just before `realCall.timeout.enter()` to avoid `IllegalStateException` if a timeout was previously set by the OkHttpClient for instance.

Comment: @lukjar This no longer works with okhttp 3.14.0. You do not have access to enter()/exit() because it is behind a private Transmitter class. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: plus this solution is very bad practise and broke as expected